# performance when storing days of week in database - bool vs. bitwise

Tags: php, mysql, performance, bitwise-operators

In one of my projects I have shops which are opened on some days and closed on the others. I have read many posts how I can do it, for example:

[Store days of week in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599969/store-days-of-week-in-a-database)
[What's the best way to store the days of the week an event takes place on in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313417/whats-the-best-way-to-store-the-days-of-the-week-an-event-takes-place-on-in-a-r)

I came to conclusion that these two options are the most used:

1. storing each day separately in database as a boolean
2. storing all days as a tinyint (0000001 etc.) and check them by bitwise operators

My questions is: I know that second option is more space saving than first one, but which one will better perform when we are talking about performance?

Comment: You are talking about a micro-optimization here.  It is unlikely that either representation will have any noticeable impact on your application.  Choose the data representation that best fits your data model.

Comment: Think bigger -- what will you do about Holidays?