# Database schema - days of the week structure

Tags: database-design

I have a tables that represent shifts (Day, Afternoon, Night) and days of the week, and locations.

I want to be able to query this data so for a given shift, on a given day of the week at a given location I can know how many staff are needed to cover the shift.

My data looks like:

```
Table_shifts
1  Day
2  Afternoon
3 Nights

Table_dow
1 Mo
2 Tu
3 We
4 Th
5 Fr
6 Sa
7 Su

Table_locations
1 Ventura
2 SanDeigo
3 OrangeCounty
```

But, most of the time the number of staff required at a location does not change with the shift or the day of week. Sometimes it is all days, Sa-Su or M-F.

Should I keep day of week 1-7,and have a record for every shift, for each day of week and each location or to how about bitwise like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599969/store-days-of-week-in-a-database) for dow?

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01159b/3).

A typical query would be : How many people needed to work on a Sunday Afternoon at Ventura?

Comment: Planning design for the future is much better and easier to do at design time than updating later on, so building it in now (even if you may never use it) would be much better/easier.  To help if you provide your table structure and what you have tried so far is helpful for us to assist you.

Comment: The key is what you wrote: **most** of the time. You did not write **always**. This means there are cases when staff does vary between days and shifts, therefore your design must cater for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is a kind of time-series question.  In general, if your table has two columns, *from_day* and *until_day*, then you can store information that belongs to a range of days.  If it turns out that some situtation applies to only one day, no problem: the two columns have the same day (say, from Wednesday until Wednesday).

You can represent each day separately, too.  It just means that to make changes, the application updates sets of rows representing the range, instead of a single one.

Probably you're going to want to represent the days as 0-6 or 1-7, depending on your system. Otherwise the DBMS has no way to know that Wednesday falls between Tuesday and Thursday: the day names have no intrinsic order.